# Is there a way to hide components from vscode auto import suggestion?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I've a generic react component called `DatePicker`, and at the same time I also have an internal component called `DatePicker` too

```
|- Components
|    |
|    |- DatePicker
|
|- Screens
|    |
|    |- MyScreen
|         |
|         |- DatePicker (I want to exclude this)
```

Now I would like to exclude the internal component from the vscode import auto suggestion... Is there a way?

How do you handle cases of this type?

Answer (score 1):

With the latest [TypeScript 4.8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#exclude-specific-files-from-auto-imports) you can now exclude some auto import suggestion.

```json
{
    // Note that `javascript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns` can be specified for JavaScript too.
    "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": [
      "**/node_modules/@types/node"
    ]
}
```

Or by searching for `auto import file exclude patterns` in your vsCode settings (`Ctrl`+ `,`).

[image]

*This functionality may not work properly, but this is the way to go*

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to conceal components from `auto-import` in vscode. It's preferable if you type the import yourself, but you may also use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and there should be two `DatePicker` on the options for you to choose from.